# Domain Driven Design - Large child collections

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository, aggregateroot

**The Problem**

How are large collections implemented in DDD that "feel" like they should be a part of the aggregate root, yet would be impractical if they were?  Here are a few examples based on my domain.

`Employee` Aggregate Root

- `Announcements` Collection
- Direct `Messages` Collection

`Product` Aggregate Root

- `Stock` Items Collection

etc. etc..

**What I'm Thinking**

I would like to keep the ability to navigate to these large collections from the aggregate root but since I'm wrapping my O/RM with Repositories lazy loading isn't really an option... Unless I implement lazy loading by injecting either the necessary repository. But I know from what I've read about DDD that domain entities should not know about any such repositories..

The other option would be to take the approach that any potentially large collection of entities in my domain *is* an Aggregate Root and should have its own repository with the required interface to get the collection of items by another aggregate root. Eg.

```
public interface IStockRepository
{
    IEnumerable<StockItem> FetchByProduct(Product product);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Aggregate Roots are not containers, repositories are.

Answer (score 2):

This "I would like to keep the ability to navigate to these large collections from the aggregate root" ... is a smell. You seem pretty obsessed, if you don't mind me saying, with the structure of your aggregate and not with its behavior, what problem(s) it is solving, any invariants that come into play. Frankly, the feeling you have is misplaced. It's a residue of our structural, database oriented way of thinking.

In general, I'd say, one should not have these large collections in the first place. For one loading them will require resources (memory, cpu, bandwidth) better spent elsewhere. From a more functional perspective people tend to not deal with large amounts at once anyway, and even computers can do more work when you break things down into units of work. As such, try to stay away from large collections and always question "why" you'd need them in the first place.

An announcement could be its own aggregate, referring to the employee by its id, so we know who the announcement was about (or for?). If the announcements are targeted at groups of employees, you might want to look into what defines that group, and model it explicitly. A direct message could also be its own aggregate because it is probably a message from one person to another. One could say the employee has the role of being a message recipient and/or sender. Again, referring to the employee aggregate by id might suffice. A stock item might be treated individually and refer to the product it represents within the stock by its productid. What is the behavior of an employee, an announcement, a direct message, a product, a stockitem? How and when does changing the state of its collaborators affect them and really, why is that? It's a means to a root cause. Find it.

All that said, there are times when you can bend the rules a bit, but they should be few.

Comment: Well truth be told I don't need large collections, most of these collections will be paged and loaded as needed (perhaps in a facebook/twitter sort of style).  So my second option then? Announcements can only be created by employees in a certain group, StockItems have state which can only transition to other states under certain conditions. etc. etc. the behaviour is their and encapsulated in the domain model, the trouble is organising it coherently.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Forum DDD example from Vaughn Vernon. He modeled the large collections out of the aggregate root. Creation is done by a factory method on the aggregate to keep control of some thing, like a dicussion can not be created when the Forum is closed. Actions are done through the AR Forum (like startDiscussion and moderatePost).

The method returns an entity (Post) that need to be saved in a separate repository (PostRepository) by the application service. Now you can have large collections without the need to load every time.

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/tree/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum